# How to test Core Location authorization prompts on Mac Catalyst?

Tags: core-location, mac-catalyst

I have a iOS app that successfully uses Core Location, including requesting authorization and tracking location.  I ported the this app to Catalyst and saw the authorization prompt the first time I launched.  However, I need to test authorization prompt and, despite removing the app and the contents of Library/Containers/<app>, I cannot seem to trigger the prompt again.

More generally, I'm wondering if there are any differences between iOS and Catalyst to request location information.

Answer (score 2):

This was driving me nuts. I went down the rabbit hole of resetting security settings via `tccutil` - which, very frustratingly, reset *everything except* location services so caused quite a few problems as I had to start re-enabling full disc access etc. etc. across a bunch of tools.

I found the answer here:

https://superuser.com/questions/526183/remove-applications-from-location-services-in-security-privacy-on-mac-os-x-10

...TL;DR copy-paste is - root shell, go to location database, take a backup, convert `plist` to text, edit it and delete your application's entry (the one that System Preferences isn't showing you, but is there anyway!), convert `plist` back to binary and restart location services.

```bash
sudo -s
cd /var/db/locationd
cp -p clients.plist clients.plist.save
plutil -convert xml1 clients.plist
vi clients.plist
# ...edit it, then...
plutil -convert binary1 clients.plist
killall -HUP locationd
```

...the `HUP` may or may not be necessary; I just ran `killall` a few times without on Monterey & that worked, but YMMV.

After that, I re-ran the Catalyst application and got the expected location services prompt.